# Laravel 8 (xampp)

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i cloned a project from github used Composer install instead of composer update, edited the Env File and i got an error

In Connection.php line 664:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.posts' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `posts` where `status` = 1 order by
> `view_count` desc limit 4)

In Connection.php line 326:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.posts' doesn't exist

I am new to laravel thus i dont understand this error. I have researched but the answers i have found are inconclusive

Comment: The error says that the table `posts` doesn't exist in a database schema called `laravel`. Ensure that you have created a database named `laravel` and then run the migrations `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the `php artisan migrate` command so that the tables should be created in your db currently, the tables are not created.

Instead of migration you can also manually add all the tables by looking into the Modals but it is not preferred.

Answer (score 0):

To create a migration, you may use the make:migration command on the Artisan CLI:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

The migration will be placed in your database/migrations folder and will contain a timestamp which allows the framework to determine the order of the migrations.

**Note:** If you receive a "class not found" error when running migrations, try running the `composer dump-autoload` command.

Here is the link if you want to know more about:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations